# Google App Engine, serving files with Jquery and Python, 2 identical files are returned instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, python-requests

I am running Flask on GAE with a google app engine backend. I submit a form on my site, send it to the backend, the backend returns an xml file and I would like to serve up that xml file. However, I have an issue serving up my file.

This is the only way I could figure out how to serve up my file, it works, but it returns 2 identical files in the browser instead of one, what am I doing wrong?

On the frontend jQuery:

```
$.get('submit',
        dat,
        function(data, status, request) {
            if (status = 'success'){
                console.log(status);
               $("body").append("<iframe src='" + request.getResponseHeader('redirect')+ "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
            }
            else 
                alert("There is an exception on server side while submitting the response!");

        }, 
        'xml');
```

On the frontend Python:

```
@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET"] )
def submit():
... do some stuff to get the data and url packaged...
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'charset':'UTF-8'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(jsonstring), headers=headers)
  response = make_response(r.text)
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/xml'
  response.headers.add("redirect", request.url)
  response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="exportChecklists.xml"'

  return response
```

Basically, I added a redirect url which was my request url to start with, so when the file was ready, I just created an hidden iFrame that modern browsers redirect to and prompt for download.

How can I modify this to only get 1 file instead of 2?

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

I have tried doing a synchronous post and still *no prompt for download*. (I am making a call to my server, and response comes as an XML file from my server).

```
var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "POST", "/submit", false );
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlHttp.send( JSON.stringify(dat ));
return xmlHttp.responseText;

Response Headers:    
Cache-Control:no-cache
content-disposition:attachment; filename="exportChecklists.xml"
Content-Length:76
content-type:application/xml
Date:Fri, 27 Dec 2013 22:59:27 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Server:Development/2.0
```

**UPDATE #2**

I still can't figure out how to do this so I only serve one file. While the below explanation is good in general, I can't figure out how to serve only 1 file using jQuery. Could someone please provide an example on how to do this.

Comment: So you issue a request to the server and it returns the XML file. Then you create an iframe and ask for the same URL again. I don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve with that.

Comment: I can't figure out how to serve up a file. If I just return the xml without the iframe the "download" option does not pop up in the browser. If I add the iframe the download option comes up twice instead of once. I am trying to figure out a way to only pop up the download option and just download the file once. The only way I could figure it out is with the iframe...is there another way to do it without the iframe?

Comment: You generally send back a download by setting the "Content-Disposition" header at the server. The value of the header should be "attachment; filename=your_favorite_name.xml".

Comment: Correct, as you can see I have done that on my python frontend (server). However, when I do that the download option on the browser does not pop up, am I making some mistake?

Comment: Should I do something different in jquery to tell browser to prompt download?

Comment: It's something that the *server* has to do; it has nothing to do with jQuery or any other client-side stuff. I don't know anything about the server-side code you're using, unfortunately.

Comment: We should try and figure out whether the iframe is added twice. and if it is, why. So - are there two invisible iframes for each response?

Comment: btw `if (status = 'success'){` should probably be `if (status == 'success'){`. but the check is unnecessary because the function is only called on success.

Comment: I did check, the I frame was not added twice... thought the == was an issue. I did a lot of tweaking around and now it downloads only once...but I can't exactly narrow down the problem... I am not sure what I did that fixed it. Was hoping someone could explain what is wrong with the concept of what I was using.

Answer (score 3):

*The only probable thing i can think of without seeing the server side code, is the following scenario:*

## SCENARIO:

First lets do some **reverse engineering**, lets examine the following snippet in your code:

```
var xmlHttp = null;
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "POST", "/submit", false );
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlHttp.send( JSON.stringify(dat ));
return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

---

**OBSERVATION 1:**

The line 6 of the snippet `return xmlHttp.responseText;` proves that the page that you're opening *outputs* something, i.e. the XML code, since you're attempting to return it.

**CONCLUSION 1:**

This output that you're printing, is one of the two XML files that get downloaded.

---

**OBSERVATION 2:**

Lets see this line of code `content-disposition:attachment; filename="exportChecklists.xml"`

This prompts the browser to download the XML, to the computer.

**CONCLUSION 2:**

This is the second XML file that gets downloaded.

---

## NOTE:

This is the best guess made by me without looking at your server code, so think before you downvote, **please...**

---

### MY RESEARCH AFTER, AlexIIP'S COMMENT:

Let's analyse the jQuery code:

```
$.get('submit',
    dat,
    function (data, status, request) {
        if (status = 'success') {
            console.log(status);
            $("body").append("<iframe src='" + request.getResponseHeader('redirect') + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
        } else alert("There is an exception on server side while submitting the response!");    
    },
    'xml');
```

Specifically this line:

```
$("body").append("<iframe src='" + request.getResponseHeader('redirect') + "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
```

when you append the result of `request.getResponseHeader('redirect')` as the source of the iframe, its clear that the request doesn't return the XML but a *redirect header attribute* that points to the XML, so, you get the XML in the iframe and the header `content-disposition:attachment; filename="exportChecklists.xml"` prompts a download, that's why, you get two downloads. (probably, the iframe and the doc, both try a download, resulting in 2 downloads..)

Now the reason why you get **no** downloads in JavaScript can be easily understood once you understand the above paragraph, what we can conclude from the above paragraph is:

**The response doesn't contain any XML, but a header of the response ("redirect") points to XML code file...**

So in JavaScript, when you do `return xmlHttp.responseText;` you are returning the text (HTML) that the response has, but what really you have is a redirect header with the url of the XML file. So to get XML, instead of:

```
return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

you shall do this:

```
return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader('redirect');
```

but the above line will return the *path* to the XML file, and hopefully prompt one download...

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, this response is the the synchronous part of my question. (Something I tried out of desperation). In fact, the synchronous part is not prompting for any downloads...it only works if I do it async as described in the first part before the Update.

Comment: i didn't get you, could you please rephrase?

Comment: The portion under "Update" is an optional part. Instead of using jquery as described before the "Update" (which returns 2 files), I tried using straight Javascript under the "Update" section...which returns nothing at all.

Comment: One more question on this topic. If i just serve up the redirect, its one way to do it, but is there a way to prompt download without serving up the redirect, with jQuery. Thats the part I can't figure out. Redirect is a workaround.

Comment: The problem is this. I have a form I want to submit to backend which generates an xml file that I want to prompt for download... I can't figure out how to do it.